# Concatenate variable argument list

Tags: java, concatenation, java-7, variadic-functions

I want to prepend a `String` to a variable list of `String` arguments.

```
public String myMethod(String... args) {
    return myOtherMethod("some string" + args);
}
```

Now, this of course will not work, because you cannot add these two types as such. How can I insert this string at the beginning of the list and then call `myOtherMethod()`?

EDIT: `myOtherMethod()` takes another `String...` as its argument. I am also limited to Java 7.

Comment: What is the type of `myOtherMethod`?  Does it accept another `String...`?  Just one `String`?

Comment: It is another `String...`

Comment: So you only need to create a new array with `"some string"` as the first element, right?

Comment: do you want to return the big concatenated string from myOtherMethod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way around creating a new `String[]`, like so:

```
public String myMethod(String... args) {
  String[] concatenatedArray = new String[args.length + 1];
  concatenatedArray[0] = "other string";
  for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { // or System.arraycopy...
    concatenatedArray[i + 1] = args[i];
  }
  return myOtherMethod(concatenatedArray);
}
```

Or, if third-party libraries are allowed, using Guava you could just write

```
return myOtherMethod(ObjectArrays.concat("other string", args));
```

Comment: You can also use `System.arraycopy(args, 0, concatenatedArray, 1, concatenatedArray.length - 1);` rather than use the `for`.

Comment: Yep.  (As I alluded to in the comment.)